# Leaked IntentReceiver although Unregistering It

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have the following code in my onCreate():

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);        
    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```

This line seems to be throwing the following error: `Activity has leaked IntentReceiver that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?`.

I just don't see how this is possible though - I completely uninstall my app and then install it again, and this is the only receiver registration in the entire app. Additionally, I am also unregistering the receiver in my onPause() method, as follows: `unregisterReceiver(onComplete)`.
Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Do you get the same effect if you move `unregisterReceiver(onComplete)` to `onDestroy()` in the activity? Although the fact that it doesn't get to `onPause()` is very odd, as far as I'm aware that only occurs if the app has crashed or is killed by the os.

Comment: Could you give more details as to when the error message is being output? Is it when you uninstall the application? When you exit the application or when you register/unregister the receiver?

Comment: @marcus.ramsden When I move it to onDestroy(), I no longer get the error, but I also don't have my onReceive() method called. Any idea why?

Comment: @TheIT It was when I was registering the receiver in onCreate()

Comment: @JohnRoberts: as TheIT suggested you aren't inadvertently overwriting your onComplete receiver are you? Are you able to share a little bit more on when you start the DownloadManager in your original question?

Comment: Actually, as @marcus.ramsden pointed out, you'll want to make sure onPause() is getting called, because if it isn't, it would explain why you are receiving the error. Additionally, moving the unregisterReceiver() call to onDestroy() should not have the effect of no longer having your onReceiver() method being called. Something odd is going on. I woould suggest you verify that both register/unregister are being called when you expect them to, then go from there.

Comment: Another idea is that registerReceiver() is being called more than once before unregisterReceiver().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you are passing in a different receiver reference to the unregisterReceiver() method? In other words, is your receiver being recreated and replacing the reference being pointed to by onComplete, such that by the time unregisterReceiver() is being called, you are unregistering a different object than what you originally registered?

As described in the comments, another potential cause for your error is if you are inadvertently calling registerReceiver() again before calling unregisterReceiver() (in other words, calling registerReceiver() twice in a row).